# Using super in Python 3+ multi-inheritance to init parent classes with parameters

Tags: python, super

I know how `super` works, it finds method from the **previous** base class by MRO.
So if I have two base classes `A` and `B`, and let `class C` inherit them, how should I use `super` to initialize `A` and `B` if they need parameters? Like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b

class C(A, B): # inherit from A and B
    def __init__(self, c):
        A.__init__(self, a=1)
        B.__init__(self, b=2) # How to use super here?
        self.c = c
```

If I use `super` in each `class`, I need to ensure the correct inheritance order:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        super().__init__(b=3)
        self.a = a

class B:
    def __init__(self, b):
        super().__init__()
        self.b = b

class C(A, B): # Here must be (A, B)
    def __init__(self, c, a):
        super().__init__(a=a)
        self.c = c
```

But this makes `A` and `B` coupled, which is really bad. How should I deal with such situation, i.e., initialize `B` by `C`? Don't use `super`? What is the most Pythonic way?

Comment: Short answer: Don't use `super`. `super` only works with multiple inheritance if the base classes are designed for multiple inheritance. When you inherit from two unrelated classes, it's best to call their constructors explicitly.

Comment: Got it! Is this a bad design to inherit from two independent classes?

Comment: That's debatable. Some say yes, others say no. Personally, I don't have a strong opinion on the topic.